# I have two Columns of names and intake ID #s in my salesforce report . I need to subtract the unique IDs from the total to show # of repeat intakes

Tags: salesforce

How do I calculate the record count of 21 unique Id from the total 46 intake names.

I would like to add this to a dashboard to show how many repeat intakes we serve.

I tried to subtract row level but since the data is text I was unable to use numerical formula